# Xfce Custom Menuelement / Menueditor

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce

So i've installed xubuntu (my first linux system ;) ) and i want to add a custom menu to the taskbar. I know that i can add a menu, and change the file that this menu is using, but how do i create such a file? It would be possible to write one per hand, but i prefer a graphical method, since it's nicer to use.
Alacarte was installed, but it was not working properly (meaning i couldn't edit anything or edit another menufile).
I've been searching for a couple hours now, and the fix [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/1089438/) is not working for me. :(
I hope anyone could help me.

Launching Alacarte after fresh install (starting, editing works, but cannot add stuff):

```
(alacarte:2614): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion 'gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed

(alacarte:2614): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion 'gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed
```

Using [this](http://lordamit.blogspot.de/2012/12/alacarte-in-lubuntu-new-item-new-menu.html) patch, i get this (alacarte doesn't start):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/alacarte", line 23, in <module>
        from Alacarte.MainWindow import main
    ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Comment: Could you provide full details of what exactly you tried?

Comment: I now added the console outputs to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!
I used [MenuLibre](http://www.smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/) and it works perfectly!
The debian can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~menulibre-dev/+archive/devel/+packages).

Comment: Since this solution works for you, please use the `accept` button to formally accept the answer.